# What happens with wallet synchronization when blockchain gets infinitely large?

Tags: blockchain

> Bitcoin-Qt initial sync can take a day to complete. You should make sure that you have enough bandwidth and storage for the full blockchain size.

What happens with wallet synchronization when blockchain gets infinitely large?

Answer (score 0):

The block chain will never get infinitely large. In fact, *nothing* will ever get infinitely large.